# Check array value exist or not using watch function in angular js

Tags: angularjs

```
<textarea ng-model="statement" name="statement"></textarea>
```

when i typing some values in text area i can trigger a function in cotroller by using

```
var autosave = function(newVal, oldVa){
    console.log('inside the function');
}
$scope.$watch('statement', autosave);
```

here i want to check the value array contain some value, if the values exist i want to trigger some function in controller

```
$scope.testAry =[];
```

i am going to push some values

```
$scope.testAry.push({username: jenson});
```

This time the array contain the values so i need to trigger a function

```
   $scope.$watch('testAry', autosave); // not working
```

can anyone help me to trigger the autosave function if the array contain at least one value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass third parameter true to watch array values:

```
$scope.$watch('testAry', autosave, true);
```

Or you may use $watchCollection.

Comment: thank you Bhojendra Nepal, $watchCollection is working for me, $scope.$watchCollection('testAry', autosave);